# How to insert sth with sed just once

Tags: sed, insert, multiline

I'm trying to substitute the first empty line in my input file with a multiline block, i. e. out of

```
one
two

three
four

five
six
```

I want to create

```
one
two

foo

three
four

five
six
```

For this I tried this `sed` script:

```
sed '/^$/i\
\
foo'
```

But it inserts at /each/ empty line.

How can I tweak this call to `sed` so that it inserts just at the first occurrence of an empty line?  Is there a way to tell `sed` that now the rest of the input should just be copied from to the output?

I do not want to switch to `awk` or other shell tools like `read` in a loop or similar.  I'm just interested in the use of `sed` for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop and print lines until the end of the file:

```
sed '/^$/{i\
\
foo
:a;n;ba}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way by replacing the `i` with a `s` command:

```
sed '0,/^$/s//\
foo\
/'
```

But I would prefer a solution using the `i` command because not everything I could want to do after the search might be easily replaceable with an `s`.

Comment: (Works only with the Gnu version of `sed`.)